# Installing softwares (including OS) in Windows Azure VM for SP installation

Tags: sharepoint-server, installation, azure, virtual-machine

I have a Windows Azure subscription. I have to create VMs with Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 OS. I need to create multiple VMs so that, I can install SharePoint in one of them, SQL Server in another, Domain Controller in the 3rd one and so on. I heard that, we cannot mount ISO images into the VMs in Azure. Also, I cannot purchase pre-built VMs, due to some licensing issues. Can anyone please guide how to install OS and softwares like SharePoint, SQL Server and so on in those VMs? I heard there is an option to create a VM in Hyper-V and then upload this VM to Azure. But the issue with this is, how do we manage the IPs / Host Name / Domain. Without the domain properly setup, we cannot install SharePoint or SQL Server. So, I am confused. I am not able to find much help. Can anyone please provide some articles / links / blogs / Tutorials, explaining everything in detail?

Comment: This question is very vaguely connected to SharePoint. It should probably be asked elsewhere (like the main Stackoverflow site or for example the ITPro network on Yammer)

Comment: When you run a Microsoft Azure VM the licensing charge is included in the running of the VM (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/licensing-faq/). Why make life difficult for yourself?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, it is related to SharePoint, since, it involves installing SharePoint on an Azure environment.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, you have to use a 3 tier Server farm installation instead of standalone.
-VM-1 -Application server
-VM-2 -Database server
-VM 3 -web server

Please take look on this article
**https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-sharepoint-farm-azure-preview/**

this [article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805947(v=office.14).aspx) might give you an Idea about structure of installation SharePoint.
BTW this question is vaguely related to SharePoint.

Comment: I have already looked at it. It doesn't seem to help much in my case.